# c++ old time to now time in hours

Tags: c++, time

Hi how can i get difference between time of creation file and nowadays and convert it to hours.

```
for (unsigned i = 0; i < strpokenter code herele.size(); i++)
{
    const char * conv_my_str = strpole[i].c_str();
    stat(conv_my_str, & stbuf);
    oldate = ctime( & stbuf.st_atime);
    cout << oldate;
    time( & rawtime);
    nowdate = ctime( & rawtime);
    cout << nowdate;
    getchar();
}
```

Comment: Well the time returned by `time` is the time in seconds since the epoch. And the time in `st_atime` is the time in seconds since the epoch. Now how do you get the difference between the two? And how do you convert that difference into hours? Think a little!

Comment: st_atime is not file creation time, it is last access time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve it by auto and chrono but there is sample with minutes if you want hours as I first said you can easily change minutes to hours in code.

```
auto now = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::minutes>(actTime - std::chrono::system_clock::from_time_t(stbuf.st_ctime)).count();
```

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at `GetFileTime` 
These 2 links might help [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724926(v=vs.85).aspx) and [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724320(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: `GetFileTime()` is windows specific (part of the windows API).  The question is not tagged in any way that suggests a windows-specific solution is needed.

Answer (score -1):

if I got you right the issue is about representing the delta time in hours... so you are not having troubles reading the creation time of the file, or the actual time...
So you can go as:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

std::string getDuration(const long ms) {

    int seconds = (int)(ms / 1000) % 60;
    int minutes = (int)((ms / (1000 * 60)) % 60);
    int hours = (int)((ms / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);

    return "H:" + std::to_string(hours) +",M:"+ std::to_string(minutes)+",S:"+ std::to_string(seconds);
}

int main() {
    long ms = 60 * 1000;
    std::cout << "Duration: " << getDuration(ms) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```